# Reporting Services returning value for null or empty cell

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I recently moved Reports that I created in Studio 2005 for SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services. In one of my reports cells that should be blank because they have no value display the same value. So instead on blank cells I get cells with the value 119. I don't know where the 119 value is coming from.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? If so, what is the solution to fixing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I'm sure this has to be a bug within sql server reporting service 2008.

A field(currency field) next to the price field that contained some no value calls was using the FIRST function. Once I removed that this resolved the problem.

I'm still trying to figure out why a function in the currency field would effect the value of the price field without the currrency field not explictly refering to the price field.